# Изменить код таким образом, чтобы не было переменных типа VAR

Tags: kotlin

Имеется такой код:

```
fun main() {
    try{
        val s = readLine();
        var digits:Array<Int> = emptyArray();
        if(s!=null)
        {
            var words = s.split(" ");
            for(c in words)
            {
                digits+=(c.toInt()/10) % 10
            }
            digits.reverse();
            var d = 0;
            while(digits.size+-d>0)
            {

                println("Штрих шеффера между ${digits[d]} и ${digits[d+1]} = ${(digits[d] and digits[d+1]).inv()}");
                d++

            }
        }
    }
    catch(s:NumberFormatException)
    {
        println("Ошибка ввода повторите попытку!")
    }
    catch(s:ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)
    {
        println("\nПрограмма успешно завершена!")
    }
```

Он выполняет побитовый штрих шеффера предпоследней цифры всех чисел, нужно оптимизировать программу так, чтобы не было переменных типа var.

Comment: `while(digits.size-1-d>0)`. Размер массива на 1 больше, чем его максимальный индекс

Comment: Ну так разберись какие переменные действительно меняют значение в ходе программы, а какие нет, и замени модификатор.

Comment: Я знаю, какие переменные у меня меняют значение в ходе программы, а какие нет, прикол в том, что я не могу модификатор (если переменная меняет значение) изменить на val, т.к будет ошибка, поэтому я и задал вопрос, как можно модифицировать данный код так, чтобы можно было обойтись без изменяемых переменных